# How can I sort a Boost matrix by column?

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, boost-ublas

I have a 2d boost matrix (`boost::numeric::ublas::matrix`) of shape (n,m), with the first column being the timestamp. However, the data I'm getting is out of order. How can I sort it with respect to the first column, and what would be the most efficient way to do so? Speed is critical in this particular application.

Comment: Can you show your code? ublas::matrix might not be the most natural choice for a task like this.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented `ublas::matrix` might not be the most natural choice for a task like this. Trying the naive approach using [`matrix_row`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/types_overview.htm#matrix_proxies) and some range magic:

**[Live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc5f1c87eaea6cbb)**

```
#define _SILENCE_ALL_CXX17_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix_proxy.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::adaptors;
using Matrix = boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<float>;
using Row = boost::numeric::ublas::matrix_row<Matrix>;

static auto by_col0 = [](Row const& a, Row const& b) { return a(0) < b(0); };

int main()
{
  constexpr int nrows = 3, ncols = 4;
  Matrix m(nrows, ncols);
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < m.size1(); ++i)
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < m.size2(); ++j)
      m(i, j) = (10 - 3.f * i) + j;
  std::cout << "before: " << m << "\n";

  auto getrow = [&](int i) { return Row(m, i); };
  sort(boost::irange(nrows) | transformed(getrow), by_col0);

  std::cout << "after: " << m << "\n";
}
```

Does sadly confirm that the abstraction of the proxy doesn't hold:

```
before: [3,4]((10,11,12,13),(7,8,9,10),(4,5,6,7))
after: [3,4]((10,11,12,13),(10,11,12,13),(10,11,12,13))|
```

Oops.

### Analysis?

I can't say I know what's wrong. [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is defined in terms of [`ValueSwappable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ValueSwappable) which at first glance seems to work fine for `matrix_row`:

```
  auto r0 = Row(m, 0);
  auto r1 = Row(m, 1);
  using std::swap;
  swap(r0, r1);
```

Prints [Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f6f9bd7b08425bb)

Maybe this starting point gives you something helpful. Since it's tricky like this, I'd highly consider using another data structure that is more conducive to your task (boost::multi_array[_ref] comes to mind).